# Cities to Metropolitan areas

Tags: database, api, geography, zipcode, google-ads-api

I have a database of cities (in both the US and the rest of the world).
The database entries are simple text strings.
Currently the database contains even small cities (population 10,000). 
I wish to use a larger scale database instead, by assigning the cities into larger geographical\metropolitan areas.
An example can be the Metropolitan areas in Google's AdWords API:

http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/adwords/docs/developer/adwords_api_us_metros.html

but I have no problem using other databases instead.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how this can be performed using existing databases\APIs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Yahoo's GeoPlanet database](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/). You can easily find what's the parent of each place (WOEID - where on earth ID).

EDIT: You can also access this database [using YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20placeTypeName%2C%20name%20from%20geo.places.ancestors%20where%20descendant_woeid%20in%20%28select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22sunnyvale%2C%20usa%22%20limit%201%29).